# Finding the index in a tuple Python

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
tuple = ('e', (('f', ('a', 'b')), ('c', 'd')))
```

how to get the positions: (binary tree)

```
[('e', '0'), ('f', '100'), ('a', '1010'), ('b', '1011' ), ('c', '110'), ('d', '111')]
```

is there any way to indexOf ?

```
arvore[0] # = e
arvore[1][0][0] # = f
arvore[1][0][1][0] # = a
arvore[1][0][1][1] # = b
arvore[1][1][0] # = c
arvore[1][1][1] # = d
```

Comment: Did you try anything? Provide us the code what you have tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to traverse the tuple recursively (like tree):

```
def traverse(t, trail=''):
    if isinstance(t, str):
        yield t, trail
        return
    for i, subtree in enumerate(t):  # left - 0, right - 1
        # yield from traverse(subtree, trail + str(i))   in Python 3.3+
        for x in traverse(subtree, trail + str(i)):
            yield x
```

Usage:

```
>>> t = ('e', (('f', ('a', 'b')), ('c', 'd')))
>>> list(traverse(t))
[('e', '0'), ('f', '100'), ('a', '1010'), ('b', '1011'), ('c', '110'), ('d', '111')]
```

BTW, don't use `tuple` as a variable name. It shadows builtin type/function [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-tuple).